industrial_ci - Add colcon arguments for selecting packages to build

I'm looking for some solutions: to add option --packages-up-to <package_name> during the colcon build and test phase. How can be it done on Github Actions?
I'd like to also add global environment variable, how can I add it? I try following solutions, but it didn't work:

      - uses: ros-industrial/industrial_ci@master
        env:
          ROS_DISTRO: ${{matrix.ROS_DISTRO}}
          global:
            - BEFORE_INIT='export HUSARION_ROS_BUILD_TYPE=simulation'

